# GDI objects leaks using Direct 2D GdiInteropRenderTarget

Tags: interop, gdi, memory-leaks, direct2d

I'm trying to render a bitmap using both Gdi and Direct 2D on a compatible render target.
I create the compatible target with D2D1_COMPATIBLE_RENDER_TARGET_OPTIONS_GDI_COMPATIBLE option and then I do as follows:

```
HDC hdc=NULL;
ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget *gdiTarget=NULL;
target->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget), (void**)&gdiTarget);
target.BeginDraw();
HRESULT hr=gdiTarget->GetDC(D2D1_DC_INITIALIZE_MODE_CLEAR, &hdc);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    /* Gdi drawing code(hdc)*/

gdiTarget->ReleaseDC(NULL);
}
/* Direct2D drawing code
target->EndDraw();
gdiTarget->Release();
```

But it seems that something goes wrong, because every time I call this render method I get many GDI objects leaks. I try doing this too:

```
HDC hdc=NULL;
ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget *gdiTarget=NULL;
target->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget), (void**)&gdiTarget);
target.BeginDraw();
HRESULT hr=gdiTarget->GetDC(D2D1_DC_INITIALIZE_MODE_CLEAR, &hdc);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
gdiTarget->ReleaseDC(NULL);
target->EndDraw();
gdiTarget->Release();
```

and i get leaks as well.
I also try with DeleteDC() or ReleaseDC() on HDC created by ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget but have no success.

Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a not released d2dBitmap that sometimes caused memory leaks, and, when I tried to release the ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget, it caused Gdi object leaks.

```
HDC hdc=NULL;
ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget *gdiTarget=NULL;
compatibleTarget->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget),(void**)&gdiTarget);
compatibleTarget.BeginDraw();
HRESULT hr=gdiTarget->GetDC(D2D1_DC_INITIALIZE_MODE_CLEAR, &hdc);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    /* Gdi drawing code(hdc)*/

gdiTarget->ReleaseDC(NULL);
}
/* Direct2D drawing code
compatibleTarget->EndDraw();
gdiTarget->Release();
ID2D1Bitmap *bitmap=NULL;
compatibleTarget->GetBitmap(&bitmap);
target->BeginDraw();
target->DrawBitmap(bitmap);
target->EndDraw();
compatibleTarget->Release();    // I thought this only enough
bitmap->Release();              // This solved the problem
```

I'm still a little confused about which type of target is better to use (DC or Hwnd), because I found different performance depending on whether or not I used the Gpu.
In particular, I found the following problems:

- If I use the DCRenderTarget I can not use hardware acceleration (or Default), because I have continued violations of protected areas of memory. This does not happen if I use HwndRenderTarget.
- If I use HwndRenderTarget, in general everything is fine, but I lose the focus on the window, which does not recognize the KeyPressed message, and, if I use the Gpu, performance fall a lot and strongly depend on the number of active targets (which does not happen if I use the software acceleration).

Has anyone encountered the same problems?
Can you recommend something about it?

Answer (score 2):

If the render target is using acceleration, then the results aren't going to be very performant.  You should strongly consider rendering natively in D2D.
The reason is you incur costs transferring from GPU to System.  I've ported a lot of drawing code to native D2D.  There are a few apis where you might need GDI (xor, etc.) but generally even those one should try an alternate approach.

I'm not sure why you are getting the leaks, but you'd want to follow the guidelines here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370971(v=vs.85).aspx

I would NOT recommend using the dc render target, that is slower than using GDI+.
Instead for a few calls needed, use the 2nd method outlined.
Also, you will need to deal with any clipping/layers that might be in effect in D2D.

Finally, you'll want to release the GDI interface *before* calling EndDraw.